# Test React confirmation window using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I've got a button in React which opens a simple confirmation window when the user clicks on it. Before I added the confirm method, the test below was green. After adding the confirm it's red. How do I need to change the test to work with the additional confirm?

React delete button:

```
const DeleteButton = (props) => {
  const handleDelete = () => {
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      props.onDelete(props.id)
    }
  };

  return (
      <Button className="btn" onClick={handleDelete}>
        <i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      </Button>
  );
};
```

Here is the test (using enzyme):

```
describe('<DeleteButton />', () => {
  it("deletes the entry", () => {
    const onDelete = sinon.spy();
    const props = {id: 1, onDelete: onDelete};
    const wrapper = shallow(<DeleteButton {...props} />);
    const deleteButton = wrapper.find(Button);

    deleteButton.simulate("click");
    expect(onDelete.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stub `confirm` using [`sinon.stub`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs).

```
describe('<DeleteImportButton />', () => {
  it("simulates delete event", () => {
    const onDeleteImport = sinon.spy();
    const props = {id: 1, onDelete: onDeleteImport};
    const wrapper = shallow(<DeleteImportButton {...props} />);
    const deleteButton = wrapper.find(Button);

    const confirmStub = sinon.stub(global, 'confirm');
    confirmStub.returns(true);
    deleteButton.simulate("click");
    expect(confirmStub.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
    expect(onDeleteImport.calledOnce).to.equal(true);

    confirmStub.restore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The test still returns false. Just in case you're wondering, to make my question simpler, I've removed the import references from my question.

Comment: Are you using real browser to run tests? Say by karma? Try `const confirmStub = sinon.stub(global, 'confirm');` instead. And verify if `confirmStub` was actually called.

Comment: No I'm running `npm test` without any browser involved. `const confirmStub = sinon.stub(global, 'confirm');` worked. Thanks a lot!