# Simulate clicking "Ok" or "Cancel" in a confirmation window using enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How do you simulate clicking on `Ok` or `Cancel` in a window.confirm using jest and enzyme?

Comment: Can you return true/false on the mockup? Those are the returns for a confirm dialog

Comment: **[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38348235/6099347)**

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I don't use `sinon`, only `enzyme`, but thanks for the link.

Comment: @SterlingArcher yes, so I ended up doing the on in the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Before the test, use `jest.fn` to mock `window.confirm`.

```
// with jest.fn, you can pass a function as the mock's implementation
// so pass something that returns `true` for yes, or `false` for no.
window.confirm = jest.fn(() => true) // always click 'yes'

// run your test code here

expect(window.confirm).toBeCalled() // or whatever assertions you want
```

I use this trick all the time to mock out `console.log` to make sure errors/status is logged properly in certain conditions.

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up doing anyway as I could not find any way to click on the confirm dialogue. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

I'd advise against changing `window.confirm`, because this change "leaks" (i.e. it affects other tests). Instead, use jest's `spyOn` function to mock and restore `window.confirm` before and after the test:

```
let confirmSpy;
beforeAll(() => {
    confirmSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'confirm');
    confirmSpy.mockImplementation(jest.fn(() => true));
});
afterAll(() => confirmSpy.mockRestore());
```